# Checkbox checked attribute behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I have a list of inputs of type checkbox in HTML, and JS uses an array variable to mark some of them as checked, like this:

```
profileData.interests.forEach(interest => {
 $(`#profile-interests input#${interest}`).attr("checked", true)
})
```

Then the user is free to check / uncheck any inputs, and once he's done, he can click save, and I need to get the list of currently checked inputs (their IDs) and put them in a variable.

If I use this code, the list of inputs will be the initial one (from the initial variable):

```
$("#profile-interests input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      newInterests.push($(this).attr('id'))
    }
})
```

If I use this code, the list of inputs is correct and corresponds to what I see on the page:

```
$("#profile-interests input:checked").each(function() {
  newInterests.push($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

What's wrong with the first option?

Thanks!

Comment: because `checked` attribute is not modified by browser, you can also see it from devtools.

Comment: [*It does not indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked -- MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#htmlattrdefchecked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attr() and prop() dont return the same thing:

```
.attr('checked'); // "checked"
// new property method
.prop('checked'); // true
```

its better to use .prop,  you'll have always boolean

Answer (score 2):

That is because `.attr()` and `.prop()` returns different things. `.prop()` should be used to check for the value of boolean properties/attributes, like `checked`, `readonly`, `disabled` and etc.

On the other hand, `$("#profile-interests input:checked")` contains the CSS `:checked` pseudo-selector that will match checked elements properly and does not rely on the mechanism used in `.attr()` (basically, functionally identical to using `.prop()`.

There are two solutions:

- Use `.prop('checked')` instead of `.attr('checked')`
- Even simpler, use `this.checked`, where this refers to the checkbox element itself

Solution 1: Use `.prop()`:

```
$("#profile-interests input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        newInterests.push($(this).attr('id'))
    }
});
```

Solution 2: Use native `checked` property:

```
$("#profile-interests input").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        newInterests.push($(this).attr('id'))
    }
});
```

On a similar note, you should avoid using `.attr()` to toggle the `checked` property. Use `.prop` instead:

```
profileData.interests.forEach(interest => {
    // Option 1:
    $(`#profile-interests input#${interest}`).prop("checked", true)

    // Option 2:
    $(`#profile-interests input#${interest}`)[0].checked = true;
});
```